# Apply StandardScaler to parts of a data set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scale, data-science

I want to use `sklearn`'s `StandardScaler`. Is it possible to apply it to some feature columns but not others?

For instance, say my `data` is:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : [3, 4,6], 'Age' : [18, 92,98], 'Weight' : [68, 59,49]})

   Age  Name  Weight
0   18     3      68
1   92     4      59
2   98     6      49


col_names = ['Name', 'Age', 'Weight']
features = data[col_names]
```

I fit and transform the `data`

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)
scaled_features = pd.DataFrame(features, columns = col_names)

       Name       Age    Weight
0 -1.069045 -1.411004  1.202703
1 -0.267261  0.623041  0.042954
2  1.336306  0.787964 -1.245657
```

But of course the names are not really integers but strings and I don't want to standardize them. How can I apply the `fit` and `transform` methods only on the columns `Age` and `Weight`?

Comment: I would like to answer a better solution: The accepted answer does not preserve column names and is therefore poor. Instead this on liner should be used: data[['Age', 'Weight']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data[['Age', 'Weight']]) –

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Introduced in v0.20 is [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) which applies transformers to a specified set of columns of an array or pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : [3, 4,6], 'Age' : [18, 92,98], 'Weight' : [68, 59,49]})

col_names = ['Name', 'Age', 'Weight']
features = data[col_names]

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ct = ColumnTransformer([
        ('somename', StandardScaler(), ['Age', 'Weight'])
    ], remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit_transform(features)
```

NB: Like Pipeline it also has a shorthand version [make_column_transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) which doesn't require naming the transformers

### Output

```
-1.41100443,  1.20270298,  3.       
 0.62304092,  0.04295368,  4.       
 0.78796352, -1.24565666,  6.
```

Comment: This is now the best answer (doesn't require you to copy a data frame)

Comment: Nice answer ! How couId preserve the column names if  I did this with a pandas dataframe ? Is there a way without having to rename all columns at the end ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, best answer and faster, although using apply is also one alternate.

Comment: The accepted answer does not preserve column names and is therefore poor. Instead use this on liner: `data[['Age', 'Weight']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data[['Age', 'Weight']])`

Comment: Either column names **or** column order needs to be preserved, otherwise it's very cumbersome to use it. Right now, the `passthrough` columns are appended to the end **and** their names are removed, so it's hard to deal with the resulting object.

Comment: To preserve column names and order see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68874492/11764049)

Answer (score 46):

### Update:

Currently the best way to handle this is to use ColumnTransformer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54322771/2285236).

---

First create a copy of your dataframe:

```
scaled_features = data.copy()
```

Don't include the Name column in the transformation:

```
col_names = ['Age', 'Weight']
features = scaled_features[col_names]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)
```

Now, don't create a new dataframe but assign the result to those two columns:

```
scaled_features[col_names] = features
print(scaled_features)


        Age  Name    Weight
0 -1.411004     3  1.202703
1  0.623041     4  0.042954
2  0.787964     6 -1.245657
```

Comment: It works but I am unable to use the 'inverse_transform' function to obtain the initial values with this method.  'test = scaled_features.iloc[1,:]' 'test_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(test)' I got the error : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,) (3,)

Comment: `scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_features[col_names].values)` works for me.

Comment: I was trying to test the `inverse_transform` function with the first row. 
Yes it works for me too but I'm losing the column `names`. I could insert it if I (re)convert the all dataframe. But what if I want to `inverse_transform` only the first line ?

Comment: Excuse me if I haven't been clear but when I mention column `name` i design the column containing the names (the 2nd column of the dataframe, the one that I don't want to scaled) not the names of the columns

Comment: Yes (not necessarily the first row, but a new line with the same structure)

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but here's my preferred solution:

```
#load data
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : [3, 4,6], 'Age' : [18, 92,98], 'Weight' : [68, 59,49]})

#list for cols to scale
cols_to_scale = ['Age','Weight']

#create and fit scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data[cols_to_scale])

#scale selected data
data[cols_to_scale] = scaler.transform(data[cols_to_scale])
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I find is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# I'm selecting only numericals to scale
numerical = temp.select_dtypes(include='float64').columns
# This will transform the selected columns and merge to the original data frame
temp.loc[:,numerical] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(temp.loc[:,numerical])
```

## Output

```
         Age  Name    Weight
0 -1.411004     3  1.202703
1  0.623041     4  0.042954
2  0.787964     6 -1.245657
```

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way to do this -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data[['Age','Weight']] = data[['Age','Weight']].apply(
                           lambda x: StandardScaler().fit_transform(x))
data
```

Output -

```
         Age  Name    Weight
0 -1.411004     3  1.202703
1  0.623041     4  0.042954
2  0.787964     6 -1.245657
```

Comment: "How can I apply the fit and transform functions only on the columns Age and Weight". I was not aware that the OP wanted to do those things.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to drop Name column before scaling then merge it back together:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : [3, 4,6], 'Age' : [18, 92,98], 'Weight' : [68, 59,49]})
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Save the variable you don't want to scale
name_var = data['Name']

# Fit scaler to your data
scaler.fit(data.drop('Name', axis = 1))

# Calculate scaled values and store them in a separate object
scaled_values = scaler.transform(data.drop('Name', axis = 1))

data = pd.DataFrame(scaled_values, index = data.index, columns = data.drop('ID', axis = 1).columns)
data['Name'] = name_var

print(data)
```