# Preserve column order after applying sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm using `Pipeline` and `ColumnTransformer` modules from `sklearn` library to perform feature engineering on my dataset.

The dataset initially looks like this:

| date | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 | 999.00 |
| 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | 899.00 |
| 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | 899.00 |
| 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 | 1709.05 |
| 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 | 1099.00 |

```
$> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2935849 entries, 0 to 2935848
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column          Dtype  
---  ------          -----  
 0   date            object 
 1   date_block_num  object  
 2   shop_id         object  
 3   item_id         object  
 4   item_price      float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 134.4+ MB
```

Then I have the following transformations:

```
num_column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("std_scaler", StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
)

num_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("percent_item_cnt_day_per_shop", PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="shop_id",
            attribute_total_name="item_cnt_day",
            new_attribute_name="%_item_cnt_day_per_shop")
        ),
        ("percent_item_cnt_day_per_item", PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="item_id",
            attribute_total_name="item_cnt_day",
            new_attribute_name="%_item_cnt_day_per_item")
        ),
        ("percent_sales_per_shop", SalesPerAttributeOverTotalSalesAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="shop_id",
            new_attribute_name="%_sales_per_shop")
        ),
        ("percent_sales_per_item", SalesPerAttributeOverTotalSalesAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="item_id",
            new_attribute_name="%_sales_per_item")
        ),
        ("num_column_transformer", num_column_transformer),
    ]
)
```

The first four `Transformers` create four new different numeric variables and the last one applies `StandardScaler` over all the numerical values of the dataset.

After executing it, I get the following data:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.092652 | -0.765612 | -0.173122 | -0.756606 | -0.379775 | 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 | 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 |
| -0.856351 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 | 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.17613 | 1.563224 | -0.396646 | 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.173278 | 1.563224 | -0.380647 | 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 |

I'd like to have the following output:

| date | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price | %_item_cnt_day_per_shop | %_item_cnt_day_per_item | %_sales_per_shop | %_sales_per_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 | -0.092652 | -0.765612 | -0.173122 | -0.756606 | -0.379775 |
| 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 |
| 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | -0.856351 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 |
| 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.17613 | 1.563224 | -0.396646 |
| 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.173278 | 1.563224 | -0.380647 |

As you can see, columns `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8` from the output corresponds to the first four columns in the original dataset. For example, I don't know where the `item_price` feature lies in the outputted table.

1. **How could I preserve the column order and names?** After that, I want to do feature engineering over categorical variables and my Transformers make use of the feature column name.
2. Am I using correctly the Scikit-Learn API?

Answer (score 20):

There's one point to be aware of when dealing with `ColumnTransformer`, which is reported within the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) as follows:

> ***The order of the columns in the transformed feature matrix follows the order of how the columns are specified in the transformers list***.

That's the reason why your `ColumnTransformer` instance messes things up. Indeed, consider this simplified example which resembles your setting:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame({
               'date': ['02.01.2013', '03.01.2013', '05.01.2013', '06.01.2013', '15.01.2013'], 
               'date_block_num': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
               'shop_id': ['59', '25', '25', '25', '25'],
               'item_id': ['22514', '2252', '2252', '2254', '2255'], 
               'item_price': [999.00, 899.00, 899.00, 1709.05, 1099.00]})

ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))], 
    remainder='passthrough')

pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df), columns=ct.get_feature_names_out())
```

[image]

As you might notice, the first column in the transformed dataframe turns out to be the *numeric* one, i.e. the one which undergoes the scaling (and *the first in the transformers list*).

Conversely, here's an example of how you can bypass such issue by postponing the scaling on numeric variables after passing through all the string variables and thus ensuring the possibility of getting the columns in your desired order:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('pass', 'passthrough', make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
])

pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df), columns=ct.get_feature_names_out())
```

[image]

To complete the picture, here is an attempt to reproduce your Pipeline (though the custom transformer is for sure slightly different from yours):

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, attribute_percent_name='shop_id', new_attribute_name='%_item_cnt_day_per_shop'):
    self.attribute_percent_name = attribute_percent_name
    self.new_attribute_name = new_attribute_name
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        df[self.new_attribute_name] = df.groupby(by=self.attribute_percent_name)[self.attribute_percent_name].transform('count') / df.shape[0]
        return df

ct_pipe = ColumnTransformer([
    ('pass', 'passthrough', make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
    ], verbose_feature_names_out=False)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('percent_item_cnt_day_per_shop', PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
        attribute_percent_name='shop_id',
        new_attribute_name='%_item_cnt_day_per_shop')
    ),
    ('percent_item_cnt_day_per_item', PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
        attribute_percent_name='item_id',
        new_attribute_name='%_item_cnt_day_per_item')
    ),
    ('column_trans', ct_pipe),
])

pd.DataFrame(pipe.fit_transform(df), columns=pipe[-1].get_feature_names_out())
```

[image]

As a final remark, observe that the `verbose_feature_names_out=False` parameter ensures that the names of the columns of the transformed dataframe do not show prefixes which refer to the different transformers in `ColumnTransformer`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer using scikit-learn 1.2.1

In [scikit-learn 1.2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_2_0.html#pandas-output-with-set-output-api) it's possible to set the output of the `ColumnTransformer` to a pandas dataframe, avoiding this transformation in a second step. Besides this, in the [answer proposed by @amiola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526434/11764049) the `ColumnTransformer` makes use of a passthrough phase to preserve the order of string-type columns with respect to numeric ones, but this only works if all the string-type columns are before the numerics. To show this I use the same example converting the `shop_id` column to numeric:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame({
               'date': ['02.01.2013', '03.01.2013', '05.01.2013', '06.01.2013', '15.01.2013'], 
               'date_block_num': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
               'shop_id': [59, 25, 25, 25, 25],
               'item_id': ['22514', '2252', '2252', '2254', '2255'], 
               'item_price': [999.00, 899.00, 899.00, 1709.05, 1099.00]})
ct = ColumnTransformer([
         ('pass', 'passthrough', make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
         ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
                      ]).set_output(transform='pandas')
out_df = ct.fit_transform(df)
out_df
```

|  | pass__date | pass__date_block_num | pass__item_id | std_scaler__shop_id | std_scaler__item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 02.01.2013 | 0 | 22514 | 2.0 | -0.402369 |
| 1 | 03.01.2013 | 0 | 2252 | -0.5 | -0.732153 |
| 2 | 05.01.2013 | 0 | 2252 | -0.5 | -0.732153 |
| 3 | 06.01.2013 | 0 | 2254 | -0.5 | 1.939261 |
| 4 | 15.01.2013 | 0 | 2255 | -0.5 | -0.072585 |

As it's possible to see the `shop_id` column is moved to the end, for the same reason also explained in amiola's answer (i.e. columns are reordered following the order of the transformation in the `ColumnTrasnformer`). To overcome this issue, you can [reorder dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/11764049) after the transformation with `verbose_feature_names_out` set to `False` to preserve the same starting column names (beware that those names must be unique, see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)). There's also no need to create a specific passthrough step.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))],
     remainder='passthrough',
     verbose_feature_names_out=False).set_output(transform='pandas')

out_df = ct.fit_transform(df)
out_df = out_df[df.columns]
out_df
```

|  | date | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 02.01.2013 | 0 | 2.0 | 22514 | -0.402369 |
| 1 | 03.01.2013 | 0 | -0.5 | 2252 | -0.732153 |
| 2 | 05.01.2013 | 0 | -0.5 | 2252 | -0.732153 |
| 3 | 06.01.2013 | 0 | -0.5 | 2254 | 1.939261 |
| 4 | 15.01.2013 | 0 | -0.5 | 2255 | -0.072585 |