# how to use ColumnTransformer() to return a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, encoder

I have a dataframe like this:

```
department      review  projects salary satisfaction bonus  avg_hrs_month   left
0   operations  0.577569    3   low         0.626759    0   180.866070      0
1   operations  0.751900    3   medium      0.443679    0   182.708149      0
2   support     0.722548    3   medium      0.446823    0   184.416084      0
3   logistics   0.675158    4   high        0.440139    0   188.707545      0
4   sales       0.676203    3   high        0.577607    1   179.821083      0
```

I want to try ColumnTransformer() and return a transformed dataframe.

```
ord_features = ["salary"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()


cat_features = ["department"]
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features ),
           ]
)

df_new = ct.fit_transform(df)
df_new
```

which gives me a 'sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'

if I use pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df)) then I'm getting a single column:

```
                            0
0   (0, 0)\t1.0\n (0, 7)\t1.0
1   (0, 0)\t2.0\n (0, 7)\t1.0
2   (0, 0)\t2.0\n (0, 10)\t1.0
3   (0, 5)\t1.0
4   (0, 9)\t1.0
```

however, I was expecting to see the transformed dataframe like this?

```
    review  projects salary satisfaction bonus  avg_hrs_month   operations support ...
0   0.577569    3    1      0.626759     0      180.866070      1           0
1   0.751900    3    2      0.443679     0      182.708149      1           0  
2   0.722548    3    2      0.446823     0      184.416084      0           1
3   0.675158    4    3      0.440139     0      188.707545      0           0
4   0.676203    3    3      0.577607     1      179.821083      0           0
```

Is it possible with ColumnTransformer()?

Comment: You can call `.toarray()` on the output of `.fit_transform()`, as follows `pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df).toarray())`. For column names, instead, you'll have to stick to something custom because `OrdinalEncoder` does not provide method `.get_feature_names_out()`, differently from `OneHotEncoder`. Eventually, for transformed column order I would suggest to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874492/preserve-column-order-after-applying-sklearn-compose-columntransformer/70526434#70526434.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As quickly sketched in the comment there are a couple of considerations to be done on your example:

- method `.fit_transform()` generally returns either a *sparse matrix* or a *numpy array*. Returning a sparse matrix serves the purpose of saving memory; think to the example where you one-hot-encode a categorical attribute with many categories. You'll end up having a matrix with many columns and a single non-zero entry per row; with a sparse matrix you can store the *location* of the non-zero element only. In these situation you can call `.toarray()` on the output of `.fit_transform()` to get a numpy array back to be passed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

  Actually, on a five-rows dataset similar to the one you provided

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({
      'department': ['operations', 'operations', 'support', 'logistics', 'sales'],
      'review': [0.577569, 0.751900, 0.722548, 0.675158, 0.676203],
      'projects': [3, 3, 3, 4, 3],
      'salary': ['low', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'high'],
      'satisfaction': [0.626759, 0.751900, 0.722548, 0.675158, 0.676203],
      'bonus': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      'avg_hrs_month': [180.866070, 182.708149, 184.416084, 188.707545, 179.821083],
      'left': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  })

  ord_features = ["salary"]
  ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()

  cat_features = ["department"]
  categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

  ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
      ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
      ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features),
  ])
  ```

  I can't reproduce your issue (namely, I directly obtain a numpy array), but basically `pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df).toarray())` should work for your case. This is the output you would get:
  [image]
- As you can see, with respect to your expected output, this only contains the transformed (ordinally encoded) *salary* column as first column and the transformed (one-hot-encoded) *department* column from the second to the last column. That's because, as you can see within the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), parameter `remainder` is set to `'drop'` by default, which implies that all columns which are not subject to transformation are dropped. To avoid this, you should set it to `'passthrough'`; this will help you to transform the columns you need and keep the other untouched.

  ```
  ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
      ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
      ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features )],
      remainder='passthrough'
  )
  ```

  This would be the output of your `pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df).toarray())` in such a case:

  [image]
- Again, as you can see also column order is not the one you would expect after the transformation. Long story short, that's because in a `ColumnTransformer`

> The order of the columns in the transformed feature matrix follows the order of how the columns are specified in the transformers list. Columns of the original feature matrix that are not specified are dropped from the resulting transformed feature matrix, unless specified in the passthrough keyword. Those columns specified with passthrough are added at the right to the output of the transformers.

I would aggest reading [Preserve column order after applying sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874492/preserve-column-order-after-applying-sklearn-compose-columntransformer/70526434#70526434) at this proposal.

- Eventually, for what concerns column names you should probably apply a custom solution passing what you want directly to the `columns` parameter to be passed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. Indeed, `OrdinalEncoder` (differently from `OneHotEncoder`) does not provide a `.get_feature_names_out()` method that makes it generally easy to pass `columns=ct.get_feature_names_out()` to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. See [ColumnTransformer & Pipeline with OHE - Is the OHE encoded field retained or removed after ct is performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527088/columntransformer-pipeline-with-ohe-is-the-ohe-encoded-field-retained-or-rem/70529343#70529343) for an example of its usage.

## Update 10/2022 - sklearn version 1.2.dev0

With `sklearn` version `1.2.0` it will be possible to solve the problem of returning a DataFrame when transforming a `ColumnTransformer` instance much more easily. Such version has not been released yet, but you can test the following in dev (version `1.2.dev0`), by installing the [nightly builds](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds) as such:

```
pip install --pre --extra-index https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple scikit-learn -U
```

The `ColumnTransformer` (and other transformers as well) now exposes a [`.set_output()`](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.set_output) method which gives the possibility to configure a transformer to output pandas DataFrames, by passing parameter `transform='pandas'` to it.

Therefore, the example becomes:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'department': ['operations', 'operations', 'support', 'logistics', 'sales'],
    'review': [0.577569, 0.751900, 0.722548, 0.675158, 0.676203],
    'projects': [3, 3, 3, 4, 3],
    'salary': ['low', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'high'],
    'satisfaction': [0.626759, 0.751900, 0.722548, 0.675158, 0.676203],
    'bonus': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'avg_hrs_month': [180.866070, 182.708149, 184.416084, 188.707545, 179.821083],
    'left': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
})

ord_features = ["salary"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()

cat_features = ["department"]
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore")

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
    ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features )],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

ct.set_output('pandas')
df_pandas = ct.fit_transform(df)
df_pandas
```

[image]

The output also becomes much easier to read as it has proper column names (indeed, at each step, the transformers of which `ColumnTransformer` is made of do have the attribute `feature_names_in_`; so you don't lose column names anymore while transforming the input).

Last note. Observe that the example now requires parameter `sparse_output=False` to be passed to the `OneHotEncoder` instance in order to work.

Answer (score 6):

### This answer skips the workaround and directly provides a solution for scikit-learn version 1.2+

From sklearn version 1.2 on, transformers can return a `pandas DataFrame` directly without further handling. It is done with `set_output`, which can be configured per estimator by calling the `set_output` method or globally by setting `set_config(transform_output="pandas")`. See [Release Highlights for scikit-learn 1.2 - Pandas output with set_output API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_2_0.html#pandas-output-with-set-output-api)

In your case the solution would be:

```
ord_features = ["salary"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()


cat_features = ["department"]
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features ),
           ]
)

# Add the following line to your code
ct.set_output(transform="pandas")

df_new = ct.fit_transform(df)
df_new
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `FunctionTransformer` it's imported to add `feature_names_out='one-to-one'` to ensure the names and location of the dataframe columns are being return by `FunctionTransformer`

```
log_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
     ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
     ('log_tranformer', FunctionTransformer(np.log1p, validate=True, feature_names_out='one-to-one'))
])
```

The dataframe columns are numbers when not using featrure_name_out

[image: The dataframe columns are numbers when not using featrure_name_out]

With feature_name_out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a dataframe from the output of column transformers as follows:

```
#a pre-proc pipeline of several transformers acting sequentially 
df_std = preproc.fit_transform( data )    ##****  np
```

You can convert it to a pandas:

```
#convert it to a DF
pd.DataFrame( df_std, columns = preproc.get_feature_names_out())
```

This is the complete example. You can copy and paste

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 

data = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,2,3,4,np.nan], 
                      'b':[1111.1,22222.2,33333.3,4433.3,5555.5], 
                      'c':['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'] })
                
display(data.head(5))

#one transformer  
imputer = ColumnTransformer( [ ('imp',SimpleImputer(),['a'])], 
remainder='passthrough',verbose_feature_names_out=False)

#another
scaler  = ColumnTransformer( [ ('scaler',MinMaxScaler(),[0,1])], 
remainder='passthrough',verbose_feature_names_out=False)

#another 
encoder  = ColumnTransformer( [ ('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[2])], 
remainder='passthrough',verbose_feature_names_out=False)

preproc = Pipeline( steps = [('imp',imputer) , 
                             ('std',scaler) , 
                             ('enc',encoder) 
                            ])

df_std = preproc.fit_transform( data )    ##****  np 

pd.DataFrame( df_std, columns = preproc.get_feature_names_out())
```