# Column transformers using NumPy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am studying this snippet and I don't understand how to column addition was constructed.

```
def column_addition(X):
    return X[:, [0]] + X[:, [1]]

def addition_pipeline():
    return make_pipeline(
        SimpleImputer(strategy="median"),
        FunctionTransformer(column_addition))

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[("accompany", addition_pipeline, ["SibSp", "Parch"])], remainder='passthrough')

preprocess = preprocessing.fit_transform(df)
```

How is the `df`, and `["SibSp", "Parch"]` running in background to create an addition in the code below

```
# How is the df and ["SibSp", "Parch"] implemented here?
# How can I replicate this as a non-function?

X[:, [0]] + X[:, [1]]
```

When I try to replace the `X` with the dataframe it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of premises to understand how this example works:

- the [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) is meant to apply transformations *serially*. Therefore, your pipeline will first impute *some columns* (we'll see later which ones; anticipation: they'll be [`'sibsp'`, `'parch'`]) with the median value and then it will apply the column addition on these same columns
- the [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) is meant to apply transformations *in parallel* on the columns that you're passing it to. In your case you're applying a single transformation on columns [`'sibsp'`, `'parch'`] and you're leaving all other columns untouched (by specifying `remainder='passthrough'`). Moreover, the transformation you're performing is the one defined by the pipeline itself (imputation + column addition).

This said, the reason why the `column_addition` function is referencing columns by index (columns `0` and `1` will be respectively `'sibsp'` and `'parch'` because you're applying transformations to them only) is that - *historically* - calling `.fit_transform()` on a `Pipeline` or a `ColumnTransformer` instance (and thus applying multiple transformations at once on a DataFrame) made you lose the DataFrame structure and transform it into a Numpy array (whose columns can be only referenced positionally). I'm emphasizing *historically* because the upcoming sklearn version will bring a big news towards this (see the link attached at the end of the answer for further details; anticipation: there'll be the possibility of maintaining the DataFrame structure while applying serial or parallel transformations).

All in all, the way to reproduce the example might be the following:

- Your version:

  ```
   import pandas as pd
   from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
   from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
   from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
   from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
   from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

   df = fetch_openml('titanic', version=1, as_frame=True)['data']

   def column_addition(X):
       return X[:, [0]] + X[:, [1]]

   addition_pipeline = make_pipeline(
       SimpleImputer(strategy="median"),
       FunctionTransformer(column_addition)
   )

   preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
       transformers=[("accompany", addition_pipeline, ["sibsp", "parch"])], remainder='passthrough')

   df_updated = pd.DataFrame(preprocessing.fit_transform(df))
  ```
- Replica:

  ```
   si = SimpleImputer(strategy="median")
   df_new = df.copy()
   df_new['sibsp_new'] = si.fit_transform(df[['sibsp']])
   df_new['parch_new'] = si.fit_transform(df[['parch']])
   df_new['addition_col'] = df_new['sibsp_new'] + df_new['parch_new']
  ```
- Proof that all's working:

  ```
   (df_new['addition_col'] == df_updated.iloc[:, 0]).all()   # gives True
  ```

Also, observe that the Titanic dataset from `openml` does not require imputation on columns `'sibsp'` and `'parch'`; however, in principle this might not be the case for you depending on the dataset you're starting from.

```
df['sibsp'].isna().sum(), df['parch'].isna().sum()   # gives (0, 0)
```

I'd suggest [how to use ColumnTransformer() to return a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933014/how-to-use-columntransformer-to-return-a-dataframe/70934371#70934371) for a couple of further details on the use of `ColumnTransformer` instances.