# How to preserve column order after applying sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer on numpy array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, scaling, transformer-model

I want to use `Pipeline` and `ColumnTransformer` modules from sklearn library to apply scaling on numpy array. Scaler is applied on some of the columns. And, I want to have the output with same column order of input.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
from sklearn.preprocessing import  MinMaxScaler


X = np.array ( [(25, 1, 2, 0),
                (30, 1, 5, 0),
                (25, 10, 2, 1),
                (25, 1, 2, 0),
                (np.nan, 10, 4, 1),
                (40, 1, 2, 1) ] )



column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [ ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(), [0,2]) ], 
     remainder='passthrough') 
      
X_scaled = column_trans.fit_transform(X)
```

The problem is that `ColumnTransformer` changes the order of columns. How can I preserve the original order of columns?

I am aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874492/preserve-column-order-after-applying-sklearn-compose-columntransformer). But, it is for pandas DataFrame. For some reasons, I cannot use DataFrame and I have to use numpy array in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by adding a transformer which will apply the inverse column permutation after the column transform:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import re


class ReorderColumnTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    index_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+$')
    
    def __init__(self, column_transformer):
        self.column_transformer = column_transformer
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        order_after_column_transform = [int( self.index_pattern.search(col).group()) for col in self.column_transformer.get_feature_names_out()]
        order_inverse = np.zeros(len(order_after_column_transform), dtype=int)
        order_inverse[order_after_column_transform] = np.arange(len(order_after_column_transform))
        return X[:, order_inverse]
```

It relies on parsing

```py
column_trans.get_feature_names_out()
# = array(['scaler__x1', 'scaler__x3', 'remainder__x0', 'remainder__x2'],
#      dtype=object)
```

to read the initial column order from the suffix number. Then computing and applying the inverse permutation.

To be used as:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
from sklearn.preprocessing import  MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X = np.array ( [(25, 1, 2, 0),
                (30, 1, 5, 0),
                (25, 10, 2, 1),
                (25, 1, 2, 0),
                (np.nan, 10, 4, 1),
                (40, 1, 2, 1) ] )



column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [ ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(), [0,2]) ], 
     remainder='passthrough') 

pipeline = make_pipeline( column_trans, ReorderColumnTransformer(column_transformer=column_trans))
X_scaled = pipeline.fit_transform(X)
#X_scaled has same column order as X
```

---

Alternative solution not relying on string parsing but reading the column slices of the column transformer:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class ReorderColumnTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, column_transformer):
        self.column_transformer = column_transformer
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        slices = self.column_transformer.output_indices_.values()
        n_cols = self.column_transformer.n_features_in_
        order_after_column_transform = [value for slice_ in slices for value in range(n_cols)[slice_]]
        
        order_inverse = np.zeros(n_cols, dtype=int)
        order_inverse[order_after_column_transform] = np.arange(n_cols)
        return X[:, order_inverse]
```

Comment: there's a mistake in your second solution. `order_after_column_transform` will always result in an ordered array since you're wrongly mapping the slice indices. To fix this, I instead got the ordering directly from the fitted transformers.`order_after_column_transform = sum([locs[2] for locs in self.column_transformer.transformers_], [])`

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnTransformer` can be used to reorder columns however you would like by passing it the column indices in the desired order.  Pairing `ColumnTransformer` with an identity `FunctionTransformer` will make it do nothing but reorder the columns. (You can create an identity `FunctionTransformer` by not assigning `func` when initializing `FunctionTransformer`, in which case the data will passed through without being transformed).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

X = np.array ( [[30, 20, 10]] )
new_column_order = [2, 1, 0]
column_reorder_transformer = make_column_transformer((FunctionTransformer(), new_column_order))
Xt = column_reorder_transformer.fit_transform(X)
print(f"Xt = {Xt}")
# arr = [[10 20 30]]
```