# Extract feature names after Pipeline usage with ColumnTransformer (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following toy code.

I use a pipeline to automatically normalize numerical variables and apply one-hot-encoding to the categorical ones.

I can get the coefficients of the linear regression model easily using `pipe['logisticregression'].coef_` but how can I get all the feature names in the right order as this appearing in the coef matrix?

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# data from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/adult-census-income
data = pd.read_csv("adult.csv")
data = data.iloc[0:3000,:]

target = "workclass"

y = data[target]
X = data.drop(columns=target)

numerical_columns_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_exclude=object)
categorical_columns_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)

numerical_columns = numerical_columns_selector(X)
categorical_columns = categorical_columns_selector(X)

ct = ColumnTransformer([  ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), categorical_columns) , 
                          ('std', StandardScaler(), numerical_columns)])
                        

model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=500)
pipe = make_pipeline(ct, model)

data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, random_state=42)

pipe.fit(data_train, target_train)

pipe['logisticregression'].coef_.shape
```

Comment: The reason why feature names are returned in a different order wrt their order in X is due to the transformations applied by the `ColumnTransformer` object and is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874492/preserve-column-order-after-applying-sklearn-compose-columntransformer/70526434#70526434. Afaik you should go with a custom solution (eg manually specifying columns to pass to the `ColumnTransformer` object) to get a transformed matrix whose features are in the same order as they were at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Then this means that since I first define the onehotencoder and then the scaler that the feature names will be in the order “transformed categorical” + numerical feature names. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: That's correct. You can see the feature names of the transformed matrix (and their order) by typing `pipe[:-1].get_feature_names_out()`. You'll also see the notation they're using to encode the transformed feature names.